# Remove TYPO3 Default wrappings and attributes

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using TemplaVoila and mapping a template to create a new site.
This is my first time in TYPO3, and all the default styling is messing up my html structure.

I want to remove stuff like divs, wrappings, `p.bodytext`, `class="csc"` etc

**How can i make TYPO3 not render any wrappings/frames for all page contents?**

PS. I know how to remove each individually, but is there a global setup to do in TS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove static files from your main template.

Click on **template**, then click on your site **root**. Choose **Info/Modify from toolbar** and then click on **Edit the whole template record**, **Includes**.

[image]

The template is named `CSS Styled Content`.

This templates are include before your css files. So in your css you can just overwrite them if you don't want to remove the whole template.

Another solution is to remove css_styled_content and add **content (default)** instead.

My last idea is to setup the styled content in your main template like this

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE &lt; lib.parseFunc
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines {
    encapsTagList = div,p,pre,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
    remapTag.DIV = P
    nonWrappedTag = P
    innerStdWrap_all.ifEmpty = <br />
    #addAttributes.P.class = bodytext
    #addAttributes.P.class.setOnly=blank  
}

# remove class statements from h tags
lib.stdheader {
    10.1.fontTag = &lt;h1&gt;|&lt;/h1&gt;
    10.2.fontTag = &lt;h2&gt;|&lt;/h2&gt;
    10.3.fontTag = &lt;h3&gt;|&lt;/h3&gt;
    10.4.fontTag = &lt;h4&gt;|&lt;/h4&gt;
    10.5.fontTag = &lt;h5&gt;|&lt;/h5&gt;
    stdWrap.dataWrap = |
}
```

Remove bodytext css:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines.addAttributes.P.class >
```

Comment: But TemplaVoila won't render without it. I would just like to extend the functionality of setting 'No Frame' in each article to a global setting in TS

Comment: Well your question is about removing, you should change that. Anyways see my update

Comment: Thanks.. I've found workarounds for most things except, how can I remove the `class="bodytext"` appearing on all my **p** tags?